# How can I make a call to load HTML content from a website?

Tags: swift, swift3, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to get HTML content from a website so I can display data within an app. How can I make a call for the HTML code in Swift 3?

Comment: Search for `WKWebView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to actually load a webpage on the screen or just retrieve the HTML source as a String/Data object?

If you just need the HTML as a response object you can do something like the following:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://www.example-url.com") {

        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

               if error != nil {

                    print(error!)

               } else {

                    if let unwrappedData = data {

                         let dataString = String(data: unwrappedData, encoding: .utf8)

                         // …handle string here…
                    }

               }
        }

        task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView.

e.g.

```
let webView = UIWebView()
let url = URL(string: "http://yourwebsite")
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```